# AngularJS - always show two digits after comma

Tags: angularjs, numbers

Is there a possibility with AngularJS to always show two digits after the comma, also if the value is 0.
My current code looks like this:

```
Sum is <b>{{vm.accountsSummary.amountOfPaidAccounts}}</b>
```

and if **vm.accountsSummary.amountOfPaidAccounts** is 0 than **0** is shown but **0.00** should be shown.
Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{{vm.accountsSummary.amountOfPaidAccounts | number:2}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use number filter,

**Syntax**

**`{{ number_expression | number : fractionSize}}`**

**Usage:**

**`Sum is <b>{{vm.accountsSummary.amountOfPaidAccounts | number: 2 }}</b>`**

**Example**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('nCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.prize = 10;
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="nCtrl">

<h1>{{prize | number: 2}}</h1>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

**Please run this snippet**

[Reference of number filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)

Answer (score 1):

```
{{parseFloat(Math.round(vm.accountsSummary.amountOfPaidAccounts * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)}}
```

Comment: I don't see any explanation of code. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try Number filter

```
{{vm.accountsSummary.amountOfPaidAccounts | number:2}}
```

Plese refer the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)

In Java Script We can use Number filter Like this

```
$filter('number')(number, fractionSize);
```